# Disclosure - White noise lead

Tags: sound-design, music

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bkk2H3Ztrfk&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dbkk2H3Ztrfk

Hello everybody! Any idea how the ostinato lead sound was made?

For me it sounds kinda like a organ. Maybe fm.
The interesting part is the change in the sound troughout the track which makes it realy evolving!

Any starter ideas? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite obviously a sound by frequency modulation synthesis, additive synthesis or a combination of FM or sampling on additive-like waveforms.

Reasons:
1) The modulation varies by pitch
2) It's a FM type of sound (bell-like, metallic)
3) It's also an additive synthesis type of sound (the organ)
4) It's more reminiscent of synthetic (i.e pure) sound, rather than a real sampled instrument.

It could be also resampled (i.e. recorded to sampler and then pitched by the sampler). Notice also the reverb.

Best approach would probably be to go through the presets of any FM synths that you may have and see if you can find something reminiscent. Then copy the parameters.

Comment: Great tipp with Modulation per pitch. By reverb you mean that the reverb is pitched?

Comment: Do you think it could be resonating white Noise with fm because of the Name?

Comment: Just notice that there's a reverb that contributes to the sound (the reverb itself is metallic and chorus-like). No, it's not white noise, because you can try to make that kind of sound from just white noise and notice that it won't really work out. If you have NI FM8, then I'm pretty sure there will be something like this in its presets (FM8 is also a pretty popular synth/FM synth).

Comment: Yeah until now i just used Operator for Bell type Sounds. I think i Test a Demo of fm8, so the reverb of the sound gets processed diferent you mean?

Comment: Operator sounds like it should work as well (or have suitable presets). No, what I said is that just notice that there's a reverb — a reverbed sound is different from a non-reverbed, so it sounds different. But obviously you'll have to get the base sound first, before applying reverb. However, reverbed sounds can also be manipulated by e.g. bitcrushing them slightly or adding some amplitude modulation, the noise floor ramps up that way (esp. with bitcrushing) and the sound can be made more fuller as well as distorted.

Comment: Ok Thanks! That bitcrushing Sounds good for that metalic Timbre!